# What are some of the miracles associated with Srikantha Sivacharya?

Tags: avatars, shaivism

Srikantha Sivacharya, aka Nilakantha Sivacharya, was a famous Shaivite acharya belonging to the Shrauta Shaiva Siddhanta sect. He's considered as an incarnation of Nilallohita among his followers. So I would like to know whether there are any miracles supposedly performed by him? Do any of his biographies document such instances?

Comment: related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22519/12071

Comment: 'too broad' is a poor reason to close your recent Q's concerning miracles performed by acharyas. 'too broad' applies to gods like Indra, Shiva, Vishnu etc. where they performed 100's of miracles. It's silly to apply that reason to acharyas. Your original post is good as such, no edit was necessary. I voted to re-open before the edit. We have a lot of noob users wasting other users' time in the process of closing/re-opening Q's.

Comment: @sv. What if Srikantha Sivacharya performed many miracles as "He's considered as an _incarnation of Nilallohita_ among his followers"?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta What do you mean by 'what if'? Did he or did he not perform 100's of miracles? If you are not too sure and want to find out, then this question shouldn't be closed as 'too broad'. Re: 'incarnation of Nilalohita' - think of it this way: If I ask for Rama's miracles, are you going to list Krishna's miracles too because both of them are Vishnu reincarnate? BTW, there's already a question on Krishna's miracles [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24739/). If Krishna's miracles are not "too broad" how are Srikantha's?

Comment: @sv. I was trying to understand y few are calling it too broad and why u are saying it's not. That's it.